# VHDL syntax error

Tags: syntax, vhdl

In my code, I have the following lines:

```
architecture Behavioral of L6 is

begin
with SEL select 
    Z <= '1111110' when '0000',
          '00110000' when '0001',
           '1111011' when '1001';
```

There's a syntax error "near ' " (the first line with a single quote), but that's all the software I'm using will tell me. Can anyone give me more help than that?

Comment: In addition to Ben's answer, all values assigned to Z (great name, especially if it's a tristate signal!) must be the same length.

Answer (score 8):

VHDL uses the single quote for single bit literals, like `'1'` and `'Z'`.

For bit vector literals, use double quotes `"0000"`, etc.

Comment: Character literals in this case an enumeration literal, likely an element of type std_ulogic , and "0000" is a string literal.  IEEE Std 1076-2008 15.6 Character literals , 15.7 String literals, See 10.5.4 Selected signal assignments, 9.3.2 Literals "The type of a string or bit string literal shall be determinable solely from the context in which the literal appears, excluding the literal itself but using the fact that the type of the literal shall be a one-dimensional array of a character type".  '000' is a syntax error not matching any lexical element.