# VHDL syntax error when using if/then statement in a process

Tags: vhdl

I am getting this message for line 16: near "'": syntax error.  I'm not sure what my mistake is.  Any help would be much appreciated!

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity SystemI is
    port (ABCD : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
          F    : out std_logic);
end entity;

architecture SystemI_arch of SystemI is

begin

    process (ABCD)
        begin

            if (ABCD='0001') then
                F <= '1';
            elsif (ABCD='0011') then
                F <= '1';
            elsif (ABCD='1001') then
                F <= '1';
            elsif (ABCD='1011') then
                F <= '1';
            else
                F <= '0';
            end if;

    end process;

end architecture;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VHDL syntax error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478821/vhdl-syntax-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using single quotation marks (`'`) in your comparison, which are used for single bit/character literals. For vectors, you need to use `"`.

Change all of your comparisons to `(ABCD="0001")` for all if/elsif statements.

EDIT:

Also, you can replace your entire process with an equivalent selected signal assignment:

```
with ABCD select 
    F <= '1' when "0001" | "0011" | "1001" | "1011", '0' when others;
```