# VHDL programming, where is the mistake?

Tags: vhdl, decode

I'm trying to write a program on Quartus to synthethize a 74hc138 decoder

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use ieee.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_SIGNED;

ENTITY demux IS
PORT (
a: IN INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 4; --bus 3 bits 
e: IN BIT_VECTOR (2 DOWNTO 0 ); --bus de 3 bits
y: OUT BIT_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
v: IN BIT_VECTOR(2 DOWNTO 0)
);
END demux;

ARCHITECTURE Archi of demux IS
BEGIN
PROCESS (a)
BEGIN
if v /= '001' THEN y <= '11111111 ; THE PROBLEM IS HERE
ELSE
CASE  a is
    when 0 => y <= y(0);
    when 1 => y <= y(1);
    when 2 => y <= y(2);
    when 3 => y <= y(3);
    when 4 => y <= y(4);
    when 5 => y <= y(5);
    when 6 => y <= y(6);
    when 7 => y <= y(7);
END CASE;
END IF;
END PROCESS;
END Archi; -->
```

> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at demux.vhd(20) near text "'";  expecting "(", or an identifier, or  unary operator

I want to have the output only if the condition on `v` is true !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VHDL syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478821/vhdl-syntax-error). There are several answered questions in tag [tag:vhdl] with Error 10500 and single quotes used for string literals. Consider searching before asking a new one. Simulators give better error messages in general than synthesizers which generally expect functional code.

Comment: This code has almost no indentations. You should indent you code when you want us to read and understand it.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
if v /= '001' THEN y <= '11111111 ;
```

should be this

```
if v /= "001" THEN y <= "11111111";
```

(i) The *literal* for a `bit_vector` is a string. Strings in VHDL require double quotes.

(ii) You were missing any kind of quote in the second literal.

Also:

(a) Why are you using `bit_vector`? You have included the `std_logic_1164` package, but then don't use it. You should use `std_logic` (etc) for synthsisable code (so then you would need the `std_logic_1164` package).

(b) Don't include packages you're not using: ie

```
use ieee.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use ieee.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_SIGNED;
```

(c) Don't use the above packages for new code anyway, use `ieee.NUMERIC_STD.all`.

Comment: especially +1 for use `ieee.NUMERIC_STD.all`

Comment: In addition, `v` should be in the sensitivity list for that process.

Comment: In addition, the case statement lists choices 0 to 7 while the selector (`a`) is `INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 4`, input `e` is not used, vector `y` is assigned single bits (and is read, which will not be permitted in VHDL versions prior 2008)... There are a lot of things to fix in this.

Comment: @scary_jeff In such a case I suggest to advise the use of `std_ulogic`, instead of `std_logic`.